# JQuery Drag and Drop List problem

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit

I have created a drag and droppable list on my website, and the drag/drop aspect of it seems to be working. Inside of each list element is a "hidden" form field which contains data assioated with each list element.

Now if I dont drag the list at all, and submit the form, everything submits as expected. However, if I dragged an element over another, the element I dragged(or any element whose DOM got shifted around) does not get submitted. Not really sure whats going on here. Here is a snippet of each draggable element:

```
<ul class="sortable ui-sortable" id="sortable_buildings">
<li class="ui-state-default" id="1" style=""><input type="hidden" name="order[]" value="128"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Carlu</li>

<li class="ui-state-default" id="1"><input type="hidden" name="order[]" value="158"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>CPR Building</li>
</ul>
```

And the JQuery magic

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#sortable_buildings").sortable();

            $('#selected_buildings').change(function(){
                $('#sortable_buildings').html('');
                var str = "";
                $("#selected_buildings option:selected").each(function () {
                   str +=  '<li class="ui-state-default" id="1"><input type="hidden" name="order[]" value="' + $(this).attr('value') + '" /><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' + $(this).text() + '</li>'
                 });
                 $("#sortable_buildings").append(str);
            });
        });
```

EDIT:

Noticed this is a problem for all items created/modified in the form. How would I properly submit the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `<form>` tag when you submit, every hidden element should be serialized and submitted. For this, I think when you are dragging an element it is going beyond the `<form>` tag hence not submitted

---

Addition: You need not to create an hidden element to store the value of the `<li>` element. You should follow this approach:

1. [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data) method to store data for any `<li>` element
2. assign a custom event handler for the form.

In this case, point (1) of your code will be:

`/* store and append <li> tag */`

```
var tempList=$("<li>other stuff but no hidden field</li>");
tempList.data("value", $(this).attr("value"); // store 128/158 whatever you want
$(target).append(tempList);

// bind form submit option
$(this).parent().bind("submit", function() 
{ 
// serialize all <li> tag with data :-)
}
```

`/* retrieve */`

Comment: Turns out I messed my form tags inside a table :(

Answer (score 2):

The problem is based on having the form tag inside the table which contains the form elements. Move the form tags outside of the table and the elements will submit properly.

P.S. I was only plagged by this in FF, IE worked fine even with the form tag inside the table.